# The content output by "for" cannot be automatically wrapped in "div"

Tags: php, html, css, for-loop

The content of "span" output by "for" cannot be automatically wrapped in "div".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGdte.jpg)

Is the first picture in the picture. The following is the general "span" content, which is displayed normally.

I mean, the width of the  should be 200px, and the content indicated by the   should be inside the  (as in the picture below). Now the opposite is true.

The code is this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "1sss", "2ddd", "3ddd", "4fff", "sdfs");
$ar = count($cars);

echo "<div style=\"background:#ccc; max-width:200px;height:100px; margin-top: 20px;\">";    
for($x = 0; $x < $ar; $x++) {
    echo "<span style=\"max-width:200px; margin:1px; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid yellow;\">".$cars[$x]."</span>";
}

echo "</div>";
?>


<div style="background:#ccc; max-width:200px;height:100px; margin-top: 20px;display:block;">

<span style="max-width:200px; margin:1px; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid yellow;">Volvo</span>
<span style="max-width:200px; margin:1px; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid yellow;">Volvo</span>
<span style="max-width:200px; margin:1px; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid yellow;">Volvo</span>
<span style="max-width:200px; margin:1px; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid yellow;">Volvo</span>
<span style="max-width:200px; margin:1px; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid yellow;">Volvo</span>
<span style="max-width:200px; margin:1px; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid yellow;">Volvo</span>
<span style="max-width:200px; margin:1px; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid yellow;">Volvo</span>
<span style="max-width:200px; margin:1px; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid yellow;">Volvo</span>




</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your issue the background not extending to full-width? I don't think I fully understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Also - shouldn't you be echoing `$cars[$x]` in there somewhere?

Comment: Second `<div..` has `display:block;`

Comment: I mean, the width of the "div" should be 200px, and the content indicated by the "for" should be inside the "span" (as in the picture below). Now the opposite is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?
I've remove the in-line style and add them in the `<style>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    background:#ccc; max-width:200px; height:100px; margin-top: 20px;
}
span {
    max-width:200px; margin:1px; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
    align-content: flex-start;
    flex:1 1 auto;
}
.flex-item {
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "1sss", "2ddd", "3ddd", "4fff", "sdfs");
$ar = count($cars);

echo "<div class='flex-container'>";
for($x = 0; $x < $ar; $x++) {
    echo "<span classe='flex-item'>".$cars[$x]."</span>";
}

echo "</div>";
?>

<div class="flex-container">

<span>Volvo</span>
<span>Volvo</span>
<span>Volvo</span>
<span>Volvo</span>
<span>Volvo</span>
<span>Volvo</span>
<span>Volvo</span>
<span>Volvo</span>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You decide exactly as I thought.